# block network connection app for mac osx

Tags: macos, networking

is it possible to block a network connection to a specific server with an osx self written app?

I tried to find some sample code on github but there was no repository for this purpose.

Comment: Put the server name in `/etc/hosts` with an IP address of 127.0.0.1 maybe?

Comment: is it possible to do it by code?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105896/block-application-access-to-network-via-a-cocoa-api-littlesnitch-apis)?

Comment: Many thanks trojanfoe! Thats exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: you could also try using a GUI app called little snitch, or another one called radio silence